# Некорректно работает анимация

Tags: android, анимация

**Что хочу сделать:**

Поле размером 10*10(**TableLayout**) и возможностью перемещать по нему **ImageView** (**не** Drag and Drop способом).

Вот xml файл разметки:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tl1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Таблица состоит из **ImageView**.
Заполняю таблицу динамически в **onCreate**:

```
ArrayList<ImageView> imgViewArray = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tl1 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tl1);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    for (int i = 0; i < _ROWS; i++) {

        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        for (int j = 0; j < _COLUMNS; j++) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

            if(j==3 && i ==3){
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle);
            }else{
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.black_background);
            }

            imgViewArray.add(imageView);

            tableRow.addView(imageView, j);
        }

        tl1.addView(tableRow, i);
    }

}
```

(Возможно можно как-то лучше создавать таблицу или грамотнее код сделать? )

Я создал таблицу с **ImageView** с черным фоном(png картинка) и один ImageView - картинка кружок.

Этот самый кружок нужно анимировано двигать.

Я это пытаюсь делать так:
я беру из **массива ImageView**(который создавал в onCreate) две соседние ImageView, вычисляю их координаты после чего анимацией перемещаю левый ImageView вправо.
Но картинка убирается и все.

```
final float xCurrentPos1, yCurrentPos1;
final float xCurrentPos2, yCurrentPos2;

    ImageView ivTemp1 = imgViewArray.get(21);
    ImageView ivTemp2 = imgViewArray.get(22);

    int[] location = new int[2];

    ivTemp1.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    xCurrentPos1=location[0];
    yCurrentPos1=location[1];

    ivTemp2.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    xCurrentPos2=location[0];
    yCurrentPos2=location[1];

    TranslateAnimation anim= new TranslateAnimation(xCurrentPos1, xCurrentPos2, yCurrentPos1, yCurrentPos2);

    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.setFillAfter(true);
    anim.setFillEnabled(true);

    ivTemp1.startAnimation(anim);
    //ivTemp1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

**Вопрос:**

Как сделать, чтобы **ImageView** с кружочком можно было передвигать по таблице(поле) ? 
Возможно, это нужно совсем по-другому делать и с помощью других компонентов?

**UPD:**

Не могу вычислить **координаты ImageView в таблице**. Все **ImageView** находятся в массиве **imgViewArray**

Разметка сейчас выглядит так:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/rootView"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

<TableLayout

    android:id="@+id/tl1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll"
    android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего картинка уходит за границы ячейки и ею перекрывается. Я бы сделал так:

1. При старте анимации делаем картинку невидимой.
2. Родительский элемент делаем `FrameLayout`-ом
3. В родитель таблицы добавляем ту же картинку c теми же координатами (координаты надо, понятное дело, вычислить) и её двигаем к цели.
4. По достижении цели анимированную картинку убираем, убираем также и картинку из точки старта
5. Добавляем картинку в конечную точку.

Comment: 1.  Это с помощью .setAnimationListener -> onAnimationStart?

Comment: 2. Как понять родительский элемент делаем FrameLayout-ом ?

Comment: 1. Да, скрывайте/показывайте картинки при старте / окончании анимации. 2. У вас сейчас `LinearLayout` и если вы в него что-то поместите - оно покажется снизу/сбоку от таблицы. А с `FrameLayout` добавленное сверху должно отобразиться.

Comment: 2.Ага, понял. Правда, мне еще нужно разместить кнопку на экране.. А FrameLayout по-моему замещает все элементы начиная с левого верхнего угла и в итоге можно только одно что-то разместить или нет ?

Comment: Можно вместо `FrameLayout` можно `RelativeLayout` поставить. В нём можно элементам указывать относительное расположене. Типа А слева от Б

Comment: Я пока что-то не могу понять Вашей логики. Если не трудно, поясните еще такие моменты: " Да, скрывайте/показывайте картинки при старте / окончании анимации." какую картинку надо скрывать ? и Зачем это делать-то ?

Comment: У вас есть картинка в ячейке таблицы. Её надо переместить в другую ячейку. Значит до начала анимации первую надо скрыть, а после окончания вторую отобразить. Сама же анимация будет воздействовать на 3 картинку, коя вообще не в таблице, а поверх её отображается.

Comment: ага, понял) спасибо!

Comment: "Сама же анимация будет воздействовать на 3 картинку, коя вообще не в таблице, а поверх её отображается." а как такое сделать ?

Comment: См. пункт 3....

Comment: "В родитель таблицы добавляем ту же картинку c теми же координатами (координаты надо, понятное дело, вычислить) и её двигаем к цели." т.е. к RelativeLayout надо методом addView добавить ImageView с нужной картинкой?

Comment: Всё верно. Главное координаты верно указать, чтобы картинка появилась точно поверх убранной.

Comment: По идеи, так как у меня в коде(первый пост) можно точно определить координаты. Сейчас буду пробовать.

Comment: Юрий, а вот еще такой вопрос: правильно ли я вообще создаю таблицу динамически ? В смысле, что я в нее вношу две картинки, одна - фон черный, другая кружок. Если я не делаю imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.black_background); то у меня выходит, что таблица состоит из одного кружка. Может есть какая-то ошибка/проблема в коде создания таблицы?

Comment: Ваш код я не смотрел, с таблицами не работал. Но фон точно можно просто для ячейки таблицы параметром `background` задать .

Comment: хм.. не выходит так. если просто задать для ячейки фон - будет таблица из одной картинки - кружочка.. я пока попробую с анимацией разобраться.

Comment: А, ну да, всё верно. Ячейка - это картинка, так что можно ей фон назначить.

Comment: "Ячейка - это картинка, так что можно ей фон назначить." Ей нужно не фон, а картинку назначить.. Или как тогда ей фон назначить и чтобы при этом таблица построилась ?

Comment: У всех View есть метод `setBackgroundResourse(int resId)`. Т.е. картинке вы можете одновременно и фон и картинку.

Comment: это да. но если так сделать: imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK); и при этом не добавлять картинку - то как-бы таблица видит это как незаполненную ячейку и в итоге показывается только картинки - кружочек.

Comment: Странно. Наверное из-за ширины/высоты ImageView. Попробуйте в фон картинку поставить)

Comment: Ага, я тоже так думаю, что у картинки есть свой размер и ячейка ее обхватывает и тогда создается вся таблица. Спасибо!)

Comment: "делаем картинку невидимой." "картинку убираем" как сделать картинку невидимой/убрать ?

Comment: Либо присвоить `setImageResource(null)`, либо `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` либо заменить ImageView на пустой методами `removeView/addView`.

Comment: Спасибо большое за Ваши ответы!